# How do I figure out what namespace I need to import from a java library?

Tags: java, jar, clojure, introspection, jodatime

I'm writing some clojure code, and I'm relying on Joda time for time handling.  The problem is that I don't know what to import and the documentation isn't terribly clear about it.  Now I know that somebody here can probably give me the correct answer in less than 5 seconds, but I'd rather know how to figure this one out on my own (aside from pouring through the docs until I find the correct answer).

If I were doing this in Python, I'd import the top-level package and use a combination of `dir` and `help` to figure out what I need to import.  Is there any way to do this in clojure?  Or are there any other kinds of java tools to figure this out?  I'd prefer something that's command-line oriented.

Comment: For the record, I found it by doing a quick google search.  It's `org.joda.time`.  But I'd still like to know a better way to find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally I'd go with David Grant's answer, but if you can't find any JavaDoc (!), but you have a jar file, you can use the jar utility to list the files in the jar.

The directory the class files are in map directly to its package name.  For example, `jar -tf joda-time-1.6.jar | more` lists DateTime.class as `org/joda/time/DateTime.class`; DateTime is in the `org.joda.time` package.

Comment: It's really not as much that I *can't* find it as much as it is that I don't *want* to find it.  :-)  If I'm already at the command-line or in emacs and I want to figure out what the import string is, it's much easier to do a `jar -tf` than it would be for me to switch to the browser and find the javadoc.

Answer (score 3):

In the same way that `dir` and `help` will examine the documentation of packages in Python, useful information in Java can be gleaned from reading the Javadocs for a particular API.  In the case of Joda Time, the web site has a direct link to the generated documentation, here:

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/index.html (see the bottom left frame)

I can't think of anything off hand that is directly comparable to what you ask, since unless you ask the classloader for a particular class, the classloader won't load it, and you won't be able to find it.

Comment: For the record, `dir` doesn't check documentation.  It introspects the object itself. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Bill Clementson has written [a small piece of code](http://bc.tech.coop/blog/081120.html) that helps you view the javadoc documentation from the REPL.

Answer (score 0):

http://dishevelled.net/Generating-Clojure-import-lines-using-SLIME.html
Makes it really easy to look up imports. Personally I just use the clojure function find-classes defined there from the REPL.